# phpgrid: howto change values of all rows in a column by program

Tags: phpgrid

I am new with phpgrid. Is it possible to change the value of all rows of one columns to another value?
And how can I change the selected status from a checkbox in the phpgrid to unchecked?
Thanks for your Help.

I can not find a answer in the online documentation

```
$dg = new C_DataGrid("SELECT DPO_ID,'Selektiert', 'Klammer',  DPO_NMI_ID as 'V', DPO_ZIELKORB as 'A', `DPO_TYP`, `DPO_BARCODE` as 'Barcode',
                            `DPO_EINGANG_AM` as 'Datum', DPO_KONTAKT as 'Kontakt', `DPO_KONTAKT_NAME` as 'Name', `DPO_BEMERKUNG`, `DPO_STANDORT_ORIGINAL` as 'O' FROM `dms_postverteilung` WHERE 1", "DPO_ID", "DMS_POSTVERTEILUNG");
```

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me? Thanks